# Replacing original VDI file with the Snap Shot made from it

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, snapshot

I have worked with Virtualbox extensively for the first time. I made a snapshot of an Ubuntu image I was working with. I have been experimenting with the VM for the last two months, and since things have worked fine I wish to put all the changes made in the Snapshot into the Original VDI.

How am I supposed to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the snapshot. VirtualBox will merge its files with any changes applied since it was created. This process may take a while and the VM has to be powered off.